# Está bien el código pero no me funciona en pseint

Tags: pseint

```
Funcion esPrimo<-primo(n)
    definir i Como Entero
    definir esPrimo Como Logico
    esPrimo=true
    Para i<-2 Hasta n-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Si n MOD i = 0 Entonces 
            esPrimo=false
        FinSi
    Fin Para
Fin Funcion


Algoritmo EjercicioPabloMelzi
    Definir n Como Entero
    Definir prim Como Logico
    Definir i Como Entero
    Escribir 'Introduce un numero'
    Leer n
    prim=primo(n)
    Si prim entonces 
      Escribir 'Es primo'
       Para i<-2 Hasta n-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
          Si primo(i) Entonces
            Escribir 'Numero primos antes de n: ',i;
          Fin Si
       FinPara
    Sino 
      Escribir 'No es primo' 
    Fin Si
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Hola, podrías plantear de mejor manera el cuerpo de la pregunta, ordena el código y colócalo en el formato para ello.

Comment: Qué significa `no me funciona`?

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en pseint, cuando yo estudiaba no se usaba, pero ya casi lo tenías. Creo que tu principal fallo es confundir la comparación "=" con la asignación "<-".

Aparte de eso, entiendo que quizás hayas cargado un perfil que te haya facilitado tu profesor. Como lo desconozco, yo no lo he aplicado y en el perfil por defecto los valores que puede tomar una variable de tipo lógico son Verdadero y Falso, en lugar de true y false, que son los que tú has empleado.

```
Funcion esPrimo <- primo(n)
    definir i Como Entero
    esPrimo <- Verdadero
    Para i <- 2 Hasta n-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Si (n MOD i) = 0 Entonces 
            esPrimo <- Falso
        FinSi
    Fin Para
Fin Funcion

Algoritmo EjercicioPabloMelzi
    Definir n Como Entero
    Definir i Como Entero
    Escribir 'Introduce un número'
    Leer n    
    Si primo(n) entonces 
        Escribir 'Es primo'
        Para i <- 1 Hasta n-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Si primo(i) Entonces
                Escribir 'Número primo antes de n: ', i;
            Fin Si
        FinPara
    Sino 
        Escribir 'No es primo' 
    Fin Si
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Como puedes observar, además de cambiar comparaciones por asignaciones y reemplazar los valores lógicos, he suprimido una serie de líneas que no son necesarias, como la variable prim en el algoritmo principal, ya que puedes usar directamente lo que devuelve primo(n) en ese bloque condicional.

Como no tengo claro la precedencia entre MOD y la comparación, cuál de las dos se ejecuta primero, he añadido paréntesis: (n MOD i) = 0

Por último, que yo sepa el 1 es considerado un número primo, así que he modificado el valor inicial de i en el bucle del algoritmo principal.

[image: Ejecución ejemplo con el número 13]